# Which is a better practice in java

Tags: java

I have a method which returns me some object let say a **String** object.

Now i have two possiblity one

```
public String someMethod(){

String data=getData(); //This method returns string

return data;
}
```

or

```
public String someMethod(){

return getData();//This method returns string

}
```

which of the above is a better practice and also a better thing considering performace/scalabilty. Please give your views supporting the answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I guess the compiler will transform both of them into the same statement (the 2nd)... 1st doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: Why should you keep a variable that is not used? The first is nonsense.

Comment: @SimonWoker I would have thought that the compiler would transform them into the same bytecode, but mine (javac 1.7.0_b147) did not.  I suspect that JIT will erase the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you aren't going to be modifying the variable then there is no reason to create a local copy of it just to return it.

The second version of the code is cleaner and more concise which is usually preferred.

An optimized compiler will most likely do the transformation for you if you don't so performance wise they're equivalent.

Comment: What do you mean by optimized compiler? you mean there are two kinds of JDK?

Comment: @JohnDoe Is there no way to tell the compiler to not optimize in Java? I was thinking in more general terms and I know there are compilers out there that you can configure to NOT optimize your code if you want to.

Comment: The compiler just writes out byte-code. If anything optimized the code, it'd be the Java Virtual machine and that probably depends on the platform, implementation and execution conditions, so there is no standard Oracle java optimizer compiler

Answer (score 1):

As with any programming language, you want to express it as concisely and clearly as possible.  They'll both compile down to the exact same thing, but the latter is much more readable and omits un-needed lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the compiler would turn the second into the first, hence optimizing it for you. It won't do that for all things, but in most instances it would. But it all depends on readability. Whatever you will be able to catch quicker, I say stick with that. But they are both the same. Only difference in the first one you are making a variable for the pointer to that string, hence "wasting" unnecessary memory. But again, the compiler will probably optimize that in that case.

Comment: andy will the compiler always also take care of the "Wastage" of unnecessary memory in case 1.

Comment: What "wastage" are you talking about? `data` is only a reference; in the worst case it's a few bytes and _nothing you should think about_ (let your compiler think about it; it is much better at this as any human can be).

Comment: nope, like I said, not all things. Java is pretty good with that, but it won't do on all things and all cases. So its really up to you to make sure when to do certain things. @twain249 said, whats the point of making a local copy of something when it won't be used. If speed or performance isn't a big deal, it doesn't hurt in terms of readability I guess, but its personal preference.

Comment: Thanks andy and anthales for your views.

Comment: My point is: Even if it wouldn't be optimized, it is still nothing to think about, because in no code, no matter how complex, would this ever be a performance or memory impact.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to come down almost entirely to style (and the first one is crappy style -- don't create things you aren't going to use).  Any good compiler would notice that there are some optimizations to be had here by eliminating the unused local variable.  It's really easy to get caught up in making minor adjustments that you view as "optimizations" but are really just an attempt for the developer to feel clever and waste time.  Even if the compiler didn't optimize the first code segment into the second code segment (and actually it could potentially be optimized even further).

When it comes to performance, the larger-picture, architecture decisions are what's really going to make a difference, not one unused allocation/assignment operation.  Don't get bogged down in line-by-line optimization.  Chances are those optimizations are better left to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd one is the better option. In the 1st one, your variable data serves no actual purpose. Anyway, I think if this thing is compiled, the compiler will change the 1st one to 2nd one anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The second is a better option because it requires less typing and reduces unnecessary code. Always try to make you code as readable as possible.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for the second solution. The less you write, the better you develop!

Comment: "The less you write, the better"... I guess you never saw these obfuscating contests

Comment: Haha, yeah, that's a bit extreme, you're right. Let change for *The less you write (but not to few though and something still intelligible enough), the better you develop!* :)

Answer (score 0):

The `first` one:

Is good on the side of writing neat and more understandable code, but it uses more `memory` in initializing a Sring object
The compiler will switch to the `first` anyway, secondly when any other developer wants to edit, he can add code directly under the first initialization, if he needs to `debug` it's also better.
Good for code management.

The `second` one:

Is better in `performance` where there is no additional object initialization, but just outputing the needed return data. But it is not a good practice in terms of code writing, but it is in terms of performance and quickness in writing code.

Comment: `But it is not a good practice in terms of code writing` please explain why you think it's not

Comment: The compiler will switch to the first anyway, secondly when any other developer wants to edit, he can add code directly under the first initialization, good for code management

Answer (score 0):

The first one can be more intuitive (in the college they show it that why and I think that´s why you doubt about this) just for the purpose of learning and debugging any possible exception but in general the second is preferred and nicer.